# Get the key from an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following format

```
Array
(
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [42321316] => 44556232
        )

    [text] => test message
    [count] => 1
)
```

I am trying to get the number '42321316' using following code

```
foreach($results as $k=>$y)
{
    echo $results[$k];
}
```

But it prints the values instead of getting the key of second array element.

Comment: foreach(array_keys($results) as $key){
    echo $key."\n";
}

Comment: There is a nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to achieve this:

```
$key = array_search('44556232', $results['messages']);
echo $key; // => 42321316
```

The above code is useful only if you know the array index beforehand. If the search key is dynamic, then you need a dynamic solution as well:

```
$keyToSearchFor = '44556232';

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        echo array_search($keyToSearchFor, $value);
        break;
    }
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/101435)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $subKey = array_search(44556232, $value);
    if (false !== $subkey) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do echo `$results ['messages'][42321316];`  instead.

Comment: OP wants the key, not the value.